# How to make cordova local notification on android sticky

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) cordova plugin and wondering if it is possible to make the local notifications sticky/non-removable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't that bad. Just set the native option "ongoing: true" in the plugin:

```
scheduleActiveAlarm = function () {
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
      id: 1,
      text: 'Test text',
      ongoing: true
  });
};
```

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling